# Parse Query objects.size always returns 0 Android

Tags: android, object, parse-platform, null, parse-server

```
public void pictureQuery() {
    friendsPic = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < friendsList.length(); i++) {
        ParseQuery parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Data");
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("firstName", "John");
        //parseQuery.whereEqualTo("userId",friendsID.get(i));
        parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        String link = objects.get(0).get("picUrl").toString();
                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        try {
                            bitmap = task.execute(link).get();
                            friendsPic.add(bitmap);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.i("FDA, done", friendsPic.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.i("FD", "0002");
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Hi guys,
I am trying to retrieve picture URL from parse server (stored as a string), originally I was trying to make a query using the Id, but also tried to hard code it using:

```
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("firstName", "John");
```

It always seems to go to the else statement of object.size() > 0 i.e.
Log.i("FD", "0002");

I think i've checked everything including:

- size of friendsList ( for the for loop )
- spelling, made sure that "Data", "firstName" and "John" are the same on Parse Server
- The value of friendsID.get(i)
- Tried to use findFirstInBackground instead (same issue)

I have also compared it with my other code for different data ( that works ) :

```
 ParseQuery parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("SportData");
       parseQuery.whereEqualTo("id", mApp.getId());
       parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
              @Override
              public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                     if (e == null) {
                         if (objects.size() > 0) {
                             saveSportData(objects.get(0), false);
                         } else if (objects.size() < 1) {
                             saveSportData(null, true);
                         }
                     } else {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
             }
       });
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong, or what may be causing it ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try making the request outside of the for loop just for testing. I doubt this has any impact, but give it a shot.

Comment: @zgc7009 Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue.